# Android video file path from media store is coming as null

Tags: android, video, null, uri, mediastore

I am trying to get the path of the video file for a video thumbnail. I'm not sure why it is still coming as null after I modified based on some solutions here. The version of android is 6.0.1.

The user clicks the floating action button and summons a gallery of videos.

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.addNote);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("video/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Video"), REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO);
        }
    });
```

When the user selects a desired video from the gallery, the video goes to the activity which it'll be sorted out.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        Uri uri = data.getData();
        Log.d(TAG, "Uri: " + uri);

        Log.d(TAG, "Uri authority: " + uri.getAuthority());

        String filemanagerstring = uri.getPath();
        Log.d(TAG, "filemanagerstring: " + filemanagerstring);

        String selectedImagePath = getPath(uri);
        Log.d(TAG, "selectedImagePath: " + selectedImagePath);
    }
}
```

The method to get the path of the video file.

```
public String getPath(Uri uri) {

    Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    int idx = 0;

    //Source not from device capture or selection
    if (cursor == null) {
        return uri.getPath();
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA);
        if (idx == -1) {
            Log.d(TAG, "uri path: " + path);
            return uri.getPath();
        }
    }
    String path =  cursor.getString(idx);
    Log.d(TAG, "path: " + path);
    cursor.close();
    return path;
}
```

Results: I got the null (-1) and got the uri's path, that's not the correct path. I need the full path of the video file.

```
Uri: content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/video%3A6174
Uri authority: com.android.providers.media.documents
filemanagerstring: /document/video:6174
**uri path: 16842794**
selectedImagePath: /document/video:6174
```

Comment: "I need the full path of the video file" -- no, you need a video thumbnail. There does not have to be a "full path", because there does not have to be a file, let alone one that you can access on the filesystem. Where is this `Uri` coming from?

Comment: The uri is coming from Uri uri = data.getData(); in the onActivityResult. The user will pick the video from the gallery (if that is what you want to know).  Thank you for a quick reply!

Comment: What is the `startActivityForResult()` call that is triggering this `onActivityResult()` call?

Comment: I added some more information in the initial post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and summons a gallery of videos

No, it does not. It allows the user to choose from any activity that supports `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` for a MIME type of `video/*`. The `Uri` that you get back can be from anything, not necessarily a "gallery" app, and not necessarily one that points to a file. The `Uri` could point to:

- A file on external storage, one that you might be able to read directly
- A file on removable storage, which you cannot access
- A file on internal storage of some other app
- The contents of a `BLOB` column in a database
- Something that has to be decrypted on the fly
- Something that does not yet exist on the device and needs to be downloaded
- And so on

> The method to get the path of the video file

The only values you can get back from that `query()`, reliably, are the `OpenableColumns`, for the size and "display name" of the content.

You need to either:

- Use a thumbnail engine that accepts a `content` `Uri` as a parameter, or
- Use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content, then use some thumbnail engine that accepts an `InputStream` as a parameter, or
- Use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content, then use that stream to make your own file that contains a copy of the bytes from the content, so you can use your own file with some thumbnail engine that requires a file, or
- Do not use `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, but instead render your own "chooser" UI by asking the `MediaStore` for all videos, as you can get thumbnails of those videos from `MediaStore` (see [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/RecyclerView/VideoList))

Comment: I need to digest this information. I'll mark this as an answer in advance. Thank you.

Comment: I decided to use the 4th option as an easiest way to get this issue fixed. This solution looks very simple comparing to the solutions I was been working with.