# /document/video:189755: No such file or directory

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I tried `ffmpeg` for splitting a `video`. I can't see any files once it's split. Anyone guide me pls

> onFailure: WARNING: linker: /data/data/com.dageek.instatoolbox_android/files/ffmpeg has text relocations. This is wasting memory and prevents security hardening. Please fix.
>
> ```
> ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
>   built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
>   configuration: --target-os=linux
>     --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/i686-linux-android- 
>     --arch=x86 --cpu=i686 --enable-runtime-cpudetect
>     --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot
>     --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype
>     --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig
>     --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver
>     --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay
>     --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc
>     --disable-shared --enable-static
>     --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config
>     --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/x86
>     --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all -march=i686'
>     --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie'
>     --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
>
>  libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
>   libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
>   libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
>   libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
>   libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
>   libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
>   libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
>   libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
>
>  /document/video:189755: No such file or directory
> ```

Comment: This is just a warning on Android 7. It is not the reason why your command did not split the video correctly. These relocations [have been discussed before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32346402/libavcodec-so-has-text-relocations).

Comment: I tested on android 5.1 mobile

Comment: I mean, for Android up to 7, this warning does not explain why your command fails.

Comment: String[] complexCommand = new String[]{"-i", path, "-ss", ((int) (start / 1000)) + BuildConfig.FLAVOR, "-t",
                ((int) (duration / 1000)) + BuildConfig.FLAVOR, "-codec", "copy", outputPath};     I tried this command.I am new to FFMPEG.Will you pls help me to resolve this

Comment: I dont get any error except that warning message

Comment: updated a post.I am getting this warning while trimming a video

Comment: Your error is *"No such file or directory"*, all the rest (including the WARNING) is just noise. Most likely, your **path** is wrong. Note that on Android, you cannot simply write `"video.mp4"`; you must provide the *full path*, e.g. `"/data/data/com.dageek.instatoolbox_android/files/video.mp4"`.

Comment: i dont set that path anywhere.

Comment: `… complexCommand = new String[]{"-i", path, …` – this **path**.

Comment: in that command path will be "/document/video:189755" and outputpath is "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/InstaToolBox/VideoSplitter/Parts/Part_1.mp4"

Comment: That's exactly it: **ffmpeg** could not find a video file `/document/video:189755`. It expects a file path, not a reference to content DB. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40161375/android-video-file-path-from-media-store-is-coming-as-null. Actually, this is exactly what your log said: `/document/video:189755: No such file or directory`. I missed this piece before, because the log output lines got joined together.

Comment: Can I mark [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40161651/192373) as resolving your problem? Would you be so kind to rename your question to mention the real cause of the problem?

Comment: yes...sure...Thanks.....

Comment: @AlexCohn I am having one issue please check the question that I have uploaded https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48642873/ffmpeg-has-text-relocations-this-is-wasting-memory-and-prevents-security-harden

Comment: @AlexCohn in node js we used like this [0:v]scale=-1:270[scaled];[scaled]pad=w=480:h=270:x=(ow-iw)/2:y=(oh-ih)/2[padded];[2:v]scale=w=${branding.size.w}:h=${branding.size.h}[branding];[padded][1:v]overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:y=(main_h-overlay_h)/2[playoverlayed];[playoverlayed][branding]overlay=x=${branding.pos.x}:y=${branding.pos.y}[output] for adding watermark.i am getting issue in that any help

Comment: Please open a separate question about the watermark, and add all relevant context info and output.

Comment: @AlexCohn   pls check this.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49400074/ffmpeg-progress-cannot-link-executable-ffmpeg-has-text-relocations