# FFmpeg file not found exception, No such file or directory

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am getting the `No such file or directory` exception on video trimming.

**video path :** `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Instagram/Fast & Furious 7 - Get Low Extended Version Video.mp4`

**file name :** `Fast & Furious 7 - Get Low Extended Version Video.mp4`

and **ffmpeg** searching for only `Fast` in`/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Instagram/Fast: No such file or directory`

I have found the issue, it is causing due to the file name having **spaces** in between them you can check in the above mentioned path and in exception.

after changing the file name its working but the changing name of every file from the device it's not the  right way so how can I solve this exception

```
FAILED with output : WARNING: linker: /data/user/0/com.example.SeekBarActivity/files/ffmpeg 
has text relocations. This is wasting memory and prevents security hardening.
Please fix. FFmpeg version n2.4.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers

built on Oct  7 2014 15:08:46 with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-
android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --
cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/sb/Source-
Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 
--enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-fontconfig 
--enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --
enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --
enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-
config=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --
prefix=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a-neon --extra-
cflags='-I/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -
U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-
all -mfpu=neon' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-
 android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-
 lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
  libavutil      54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
  libavcodec     56.  1.100 / 56.  1.100
  libavformat    56.  4.101 / 56.  4.101
  libavdevice    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
  libavfilter     5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libswscale      3.  0.100 /  3.  0.100
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  0.100 / 53.  0.100
  /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Instagram/Fast: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Have you tried to encapsulate the path in a single quote i.e `"'yourparh'"`

Comment: @Niza Siwale I am selecting video dynamically so how can I pass path like this

Comment: What do you mean by dynamically? Are you doing it programmatically

Comment: Please change the title of your question, it is completely misleading.

Comment: @AlexCohn `execFFmpegBinary("-i " + path + " -ss " + startMs / 1000 + " -to " + endMs / 1000 + " -c copy " + destPath)` this is my code. I have tried `'` using this but not working for me please help...

Comment: When you prepare the arguments for ffmpeg, you should enclose the filename in ', as @NizaSiwale says. E.g. ffmpeg.execute(… + "-i '" + filepath + "'"); – Alex Cohn

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace

```
execFFmpegBinary("-i " + path + " -ss " + startMs / 1000 + 
       " -to " + endMs / 1000 + " -c copy " + destPath);
```

with

```
execFFmpegBinary(new String[] {"-i", path, "-ss", "" + startMs / 1000,           
       "-to", "" + endMs / 1000, "-c", "copy", destPath});
```

The [fix](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java/issues/35) to **ffmpeg-android-java** dates back to 2015.

Comment: not working for me . file name : `Fast & Furious 7 - Get Low Extended Version Video.mp4` and `ffmpeg` searching for only `Fast ` like `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Instagram/Fast` No such file or directory i think the name of file is issue

Comment: `execFFmpegBinary("-i " + path + " -ss " + startMs / 1000 + " -to " + endMs / 1000 + " -c copy " +  dest.getAbsolutePath())` this is working for me when I change file name with no spaces/single string ,on changing file name your code not working might be some thing wrong please check

Comment: I am somewhat puzzled: I see [execFFmpegBinary()](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java/blob/6fd8356ff41c4443dc84c6f0bce478bf5d4c4122/app/src/main/java/com/github/hiteshsondhi88/sampleffmpeg/Home.java#L78) that takes String[], not a single String parameter.

Comment: See https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java/issues/35 - the fix dates back to 2015.

Comment: thanks for your help till the time I have managed by changing file name programmatically  before passing args.

Answer (score 0):

Try to escape the spaces with \

```
execFFmpegBinary("-i '/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Instagram/Fast\ &\ Furious\ 7\ -\ Get\ Low\ Extended\ Version\ Video.mp4'"  + "-ss " + startMs / 1000 +
       " -to " + endMs / 1000 + " -c copy " + destPath);
```

Comment: on video select I am getting video path so how can I escape with ` \ ` while file conversion? will  It  create problem or not? because `ffmpeg` search for original file in directory .Till the time I am programmatically renaming file name before conversion and then I am passing new path to `ffmpeg` but this is not the right way of doing something should be there.

Answer (score 0):

Replying late to this question, but I thought I would add it anyway.. This is how I execute commands:

```
String[] s = {"-i" ,sourcePath,"-crf","18","-c:v","libx264","-preset","ultrafast",directoryToStore+"/"+outputName};
s.execFFmpegBinary();
```

I've tested using files with name spaces and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just surround your path with single quotations. The command is confused with the spaces in the file name.